# Why does using a function namespace drastically increase overhead?

Tags: r

Example:

```
time <- Sys.time()
total <- 0
for(i in 1:1e6) {
  total <- total + stats::pnorm(i/1e6)
}
print(Sys.time() - time)
```

Time difference of 8.703019 secs

```
time <- Sys.time()
total <- 0
for(i in 1:1e6) {
  total <- total + pnorm(i/1e6)
}
print(Sys.time() - time)
```

Time difference of 1.291625 secs

Comment: My guess is that when a package is loaded with `library()` or by default (as is the case for the `stats` package), R has direct access to its functions. However, when you use a package's namespace, there is an additional step of accessing the package then the function of interest. This additional step, in your case, is performed a million times.